# out of bounds error when down sampling image

Tags: python, image, list, matrix

Does anyone know why my index `matrix[k][m]=sum/9` is out of range? I'm pretty sure that my solution is correct. I tried debugging it, but I still cannot think 
why it's not working.

```
def downsample_by_3(image):

    matrix_image = copy.deepcopy(image)
    matrix=[ [], [], [] ]
    k=0
    m=0
    for i in range(0,len(matrix_image),3):

        for j in range(0,len(matrix_image[i]),3):


            sum=0

            for r in range(i,i+3):
                for c in range(j,j+3):
                    sum+=matrix_image[r][c]
            m+=1
            matrix[k][m]=sum/9

        m=0
        k+=1

    return matrix
```

The image is presented as a matrix (list of lists).

Let's say I took this list,

```
print(downsample_by_3([[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]]))
```

it should return a list with 18.

Another example of it to understand it better:

[image: better example]

Comment: Shall we assume you're avoiding numpy/scipy for learning/homework purposes?

Comment: Your words and image imply that you simply want to sum the elements within a block, while in your code you take the average. Which one is it?

Comment: Yes because homework purposes, i want to do the average not the sum

Comment: So your example up above should actually have 1 and 2 instead of 9 and 18 in the downsampled sample drawing above. :)  The idea is to reduce image resolution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of empty lists. So while `matrix[0]` is fine, `matrix[0][0]` is out of bounds.

You have to either preallocate the lengths of the sublists beforehand if you wish to access them by index, or you append the averages as shown in Gary02127's answer. If you choose the former, you must also increment `m` **after** `matrix[k][m]=sum/9`.

However, your code has another out-of-bounds bug waiting to be triggered. Suppose you have a 3x4 image, i.e., one of the dimensions isn't divisible by 3. You average the first 3x3 block just fine, and then you try to access the pixels at column indices 3-5.

If your dimensions aren't divisible by the downsample factor, you have 3 choices:

1. raise an error at the beginning of the function call,
2. add extra rows/columns to make your matrix divisible by your factor (you can use the value of the last element of the row/column to extend it further), or
3. use only as many elements are you have left.

Here's an implementation with approach #3 and preallocating your matrix.

```
def downsample(image, factor):
    height = len(image)
    # this assumes that all sublists have the same length!
    width = len(image[0])
    matrix = [[None] * ((width + factor - 1) // factor)
              for _ in range((height + factor - 1) // factor)]
    k = 0
    m = 0
    for i in range(0, height, factor):
        for j in range(0, width, factor):
            # don't overshadow the `sum` builtin
            total = 0
            count = 0
            for r in range(i, min(i+factor, height)):
                for c in range(j, min(j+factor, width)):
                    total += image[r][c]
                    count += 1
            matrix[k][m] = total / count
            m += 1
        m = 0
        k += 1
    return matrix
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I didnt take in mind the another out of bounds error aswell this has worked out well for me now !!

Answer (score 0):

You start with `matrix` hard-coded to a sequence of empty lists `matrix=[ [], [], [] ]`, and then in the

```
matrix[k][m]=sum/9
```

line, you try to force a value into one of those slots, but there are no slots. The *k* will be okay for the first few (from 0 through 2), but the *m* is going to error right away.  Seems like you need to dynamically create `matrix` on the fly.  Maybe

```
matrix[k].append(sum/9)
```

Also, a `return matrix` at the end your function wouldn't hurt.  :)

The above should help you move forward. At least it gives running code.

Comment: Thanks I understand it better now! , I tried the append it worked but only for the first element its because i done something wrong

Comment: @OdayHajYehia - I'm glad it helped. Please click on the up arrow to give me points if you feel the information was helpful.